# GCC, empty structs, and -Wunused-result

Tags: gcc

The following program causes gcc to emit -Wunused-result:

```
struct Empty { };

__attribute__((warn_unused_result))
static struct Empty func(void) {
  return (struct Empty){};
}

int main(void) {
  struct Empty res = func();
  (void)res;
  return 0;
}
```

Compiler output:

```
gcc -Wall -Wextra /tmp/test.c -c -o /tmp/test
/tmp/test.c: In function ‘main’:
/tmp/test.c:12:22: warning: ignoring return value of ‘func’, declared with attribute warn_unused_result [-Wunused-result]
   struct Empty res = func();
                      ^~~~~~
```

clang doesn't emit a warning.

Is this a bug or a feature?

(Empty struct as return value is useful in some code generation scenarios where a return value is always expected, but *that is beside the question*)

Comment: This looks like a bug to me, because it doesn't help to _actually_ use `res`. (Casting to void is intentionally not sufficient to suppress this warning.) I can reproduce the problem with gcc 7 (https://godbolt.org/g/mHAHsH), so please file a bug report at https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/ .

Comment: @zwol unfortunately user account creation is not working on the gcc bugzilla

Comment: Oh right.  I filed it for you: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=82134

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does indeed appear to be a bug in GCC.  I filed [a bug report](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=82134) with them.

A workaround is to include a nameless bitfield in the "empty" structure:

```
struct Empty {char:1;};

extern void use_empty(struct Empty);

__attribute__((warn_unused_result))
extern struct Empty make_empty(void);

void should_warn(void)
{
    make_empty();
}

void shouldnt_warn_1(void)
{
    use_empty(make_empty());
}

void shouldnt_warn_2(void)
{
    struct Empty e = make_empty();
    use_empty(e);
}
```

warns only for 'should_warn'.  This does mean that `sizeof(struct Empty)` is 1 rather than 0, and GCC generates an additional move instruction in both `shouldnt_warn_1` and `shouldnt_warn_2`, but those are probably acceptable side-effects.

(Note that both a struct with no fields at all, and a struct with no *named* fields, are GNU extensions — in ISO C you must include at least one named field in every struct.  Nameless bitfields, however, are standard, just obscure.)